# ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image on fromarray()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, valueerror

I am already providing cropped images as a NumPy array. After some iterations, it is giving this error randomly. This is the function I am using.

```py
 def feedImage(model,img,required_size=(160, 160)):
    # print(img)
    image = Image.fromarray(img)
    # convert to RGB, if needed
    image = image.convert('RGB')
    # convert to array
    pixels = asarray(image)
    image = Image.fromarray(pixels)
    image = image.resize(required_size)
    face_array = asarray(image)
    classname,prob = get_embedding(model,face_array)
    return classname,prob
```

This is the generated error

```
, line 16, in feedImage
    image = Image.fromarray(img)
  File "/home/anupam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2701, in fromarray
    return frombuffer(mode, size, obj, "raw", rawmode, 0, 1)
  File "/home/anupam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2641, in frombuffer
    return frombytes(mode, size, data, decoder_name, args)
  File "/home/anupam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2581, in frombytes
    im.frombytes(data, decoder_name, args)
  File "/home/anupam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 768, in frombytes
    d.setimage(self.im)
ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image
```

Comment: Add your piece of code.

Comment: Added the function I am using.

Comment: It is preferable that you provide the error not as an image but text, just as you posted the code.